# Aframe / Squarespace - How to make OBJ source available to all

Tags: html, src, aframe, squarespace, .obj

Newbie here. I created html incorporating Aframe assets that I am inputting into the Squarespace code editor. Everything loads in fine except for the obj files. How to I link to the obj file I have in a folder on my desktop? Or can I upload the obj file online and link the source through the web?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload your OBJ (and any image or `.mtl` files connected with it) to a file hosting service. Two (Github Pages and Uploadcare) are mentioned in the [A-Frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load), along with links / documentation.

[Squarespace has its own file hosting service](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files), but whether this will work with OBJ files and A-Frame, I don't know.